# Can I perform conformance checking for process mining in R?

Tags: r, data-mining

I am new to process mining field and I am trying to do process mining in R with "bupaR" package.
is there a way to perform conformance checking in R?

I know there is a package called "pmineR" that performs conformance checking, I have tried this but I can't figure out the result.
unfortunately, online help about this function in "pmineR" package doesn't provide sufficient support.

below, you can find the code that I have used for conformance checking:

```
library(pMineR)

confCheck_easy(verbose.mode = TRUE)
```

all in all, I want to know if it is possible to do conformance checking in R and if so, I would be thankful if the right package and the guide to use that package could be provided.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible with the `bupaR` package in R. Install it via `install.packages("bupar")` or check out the [website](https://www.bupar.net/).